# Changing ParametricPlot to ParametricPlot3D with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

I have some code that I am happy with:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]; Show[
   Table[sol = 
     NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], 
         t] == (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/(Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), 
       xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}];
     ParametricPlot[{xtraj[t], t} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> All], {n, -3, 4 - 1, 1}]]
```

But I want to add a 3rd axis with the following equation:

```
 P1 = (E^(-(1/2) (t + x - xi)^2 σ^2) Sqrt[π/ 2] σ (1 + E^(2 x (t - xi) σ^2) + 
      2 E^(x (t - xi) σ^2) Cos[2 k0 x]))
```

REMEMBER: I am using the value of `xtraj[t]` to plot, not `sol`.

So it will be a 3D plot with: `xtraj[t]`, `t`, `P1`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is this close to what you need: `k0 = 1;
\[Sigma] = 1;
xi = 1;
p1 = (E^(-(1/2) (t + x - xi)^2 \[Sigma]^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] \[Sigma] (1 +
       E^(2 x (t - xi) \[Sigma]^2) + 
      2 E^(x (t - xi) \[Sigma]^2) Cos[2 k0 x]));
Show[Table[
  sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], 
       t] == (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/(Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), 
     xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}];
  ParametricPlot3D[{xtraj[t], t, p1 /. x -> xtraj[t]} /. sol, {t,
     0, 4}, PlotRange -> All], {n, -3, 4 - 1, 1}]]`?

Comment: Looks close but it only shows lines, really need a sheet.

Comment: Betty, noticed you haven't cast any votes. Please see [MichaelE2's comment here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173905/125) .

Answer (score 1):

```
k0 = 1; σ = 1; xi = 1;
p1 = (E^(-(1/2) (t + x - xi)^2 σ^2) Sqrt[π/2] σ (1 + E^(2 x (t - xi) σ^2) + 
   2 E^(x (t - xi) σ^2) Cos[2 k0 x]));
data3d = Flatten[Table[sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], t] == (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/
    (Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]), xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}];
  Table[{xtraj[t], t, p1 /. x -> xtraj[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 4, .1}], {n, -3, 4 - 1, 1}], 2];
lpp3d = ListPlot3D[data3d, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None];

pp3d = Show[Table[sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], t] == (Sinh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)])/
   (Cosh[2 xtraj[t] (t - 2)]),  xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}]; 
 ParametricPlot3D[{xtraj[t], t, p1 /. x -> xtraj[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]], {n, -3, 4 - 1, 1}]];


Show[lpp3d, pp3d]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to get the function `xtraj` parametrizes by `n` and use it in three-argument form of `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
xtraj2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[y[t], t] == Sinh[2 y[t] (t - 2)]/Cosh[2 y[t] (t - 2)], 
 y[0] == n}, y, {t, 0, 4}, {n}];
ParametricPlot3D[{xtraj2[n][t], t, p1 /. x -> xtraj2[n][t]}, {t, 0, 4}, {n, -4, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, Mesh -> {Range[-3, 3]}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: That is looking nice - how about the sheet and the lines together that would really show the detail.

Comment: Thanks - you are super helpful. Is the an option to change the colour of the sheet?

Comment: @Betty, try `PlotStyle->Blue` or `ColorFunction ->"Rainbow"` in `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Thanks so much kglr

Comment: I perfer the one before it - but what about opacity of the sheet?

Comment: Is there also a way to control the xtraj[t] axis, as there is some cutoff there?

Comment: Betty, try `PlotStyle->Opacity[.5,.Blue]`  to add opacity. To control the region, see [RegionFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html)

Comment: Thank you kglr that is very helpful.